# c# mongodb batch insert

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I want to import csv file to MongoDB. The csv file have 3,00,000 records and 10 fields. I can't find good tutorial for InsertBatch method described in MongoDB documentation. Inserting records one by one using insert() method is taking more than 15 Minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/) helps you ?

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> books;

List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();

using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader("users.csv"))
{
    batch.add(
        new BsonDocument {
            { "field1", reader["field1"] },
            { "field2", reader["field2"] }
        }),
};
books.InsertBatch(batch.ToArray());
```

Comment: It's ok but how to create BsonDocument dynamically ie, reading CSV file ?

Comment: There is a lot of .NET libraries to read csv files, [like this one](http://www.csvreader.com).

Comment: I edited my post to give you a sample with the CSV library i linked.

Comment: I am getting the following error

`use of unsigned local variable 'books'`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks elpaulo for your help. I modified the code and try bulkinsert test code. Here is the full code

```
var mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.44.4.59");
MongoServer server = mongo.GetServer();

MongoDatabase test = server.GetDatabase("server_info");
var category = test.GetCollection("test_collection");

List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();

for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
{
   batch.Add(
       new BsonDocument {
           { "field1", 1 },
           { "field2", 2 },
           { "field3", 3 },
           { "field4", 4 }
        });
}
category.InsertBatch(batch);
```

It take about 30sec to insert this much data. Once again thanks for your help.